# embed google maps with search and locator functionality in drupal 7..?

Tags: drupal, google-maps, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I Want to to create a page in my drupal 7 site with a google map on it, which shows hospitals, clinics and pharmacies near the user.

I tried, [location](http://drupal.org/project/locationmap) module and [openLayerslocator](http://drupal.org/project/ol_locator). But I couldn't figure how to achieve it using these modules. Initially I came to know that, I can use to openLayers locator, but there is no documentation or guide that's available to achieve it.

But as far as I understand, both modules work in a similar way but NOT as I want it to. In both module, I will have a content type called 'Location' and it will as for address,zip code etc while creating the content with that type. Then there will be a view, which takes these address from those 'Location' noddes and displays those addresses on a google map..! But THAT'S NOT WHAT I WANT.

**I do not want user to create any content or anything, the map sits there as a page where user visits it, to see what are the hospitals etc are there around him. When user navigates to that page, he will just enter his city, address or zipcode (like in a form and hits find) to see what are the hospitals around him (let's say around a distance of 50km). By default, when he navigates to the page, the map should be showing those places like hospitals and clinics around his default address (It will be available from the database.).**

So how can I achieve it...??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you expect to pull in the "places of interest" as nodes? and then use the visitors geolocation to find the nearest? if so this is easily accomplished via geofield/geocoder/address and openlayers modules.